# Is covering the youtube player iframe with a DIV a violation of the API terms of service

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-data-api

I'm thinking of using a transparent DIV to disable modest branding when a user hovers over the player. Would doing this violate the terms of service for using the Youtube API? I have researched online, and read through the the TOS, but I can't find a definitive answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question of legal interpretation and not a question about programming.

Comment: @Bobulous could you recommend a stack where this question would be more appropriate?

Comment: To find out whether other site developers have been reprimanded or punished by Google for the suggested change, maybe ask in [Webmaster Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). But be aware that you're unlikely to receive reliable legal advice online, and in honesty the only people who can answer your question are Google themselves.